# MFSideMenuPanModeDefault gives me nil value error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, null, mfslidemenu

I'm using `MFSideMenu` with swift. when I use following in `viewWillAppear`,

```
menuContainerViewController.panMode =  MFSideMenuPanModeDefault
```

it says `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and app crashes. What can be the reason for this.

Comment: can add some more code

Comment: move your code to viewDidAppear and try once

Comment: still crashes, I have no idea

Comment: @subash, are you sure that you initialised `menuContainerViewController `?

Comment: how, I think so ! @KrishnaCA

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I do nothing than this. it just crash on this point. 
previously it works fine. (I navigate from `viewcontrollerA` to `this view controller`). but now I navigate `viewcontrollerB -> viewcontrollerA to then this veiw controller`. after that I got this error